# Turn this into a service or factory to share function between different controllers

Tags: angularjs

I have this controller, it contains a function which takes the input name (fullname) and splits it into fname (first names) and lname (last name).
I'd like to separate the function from this controller so that I can share it between controllers. Not sure how to do it.

```
appControllers.controller('ContactCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.page.setDirection('none');
$scope.splitName = function (fullName) {
  var formData = {},
      nameArr = fullName.split(' ');
  if (nameArr.length == 1) {
    formData.first_name = nameArr[0];
    formData.last_name = '';
  } else if (nameArr.length > 2) {
    formData.last_name = nameArr.pop();
    formData.first_name = nameArr.join(' ');
  } else {
    formData.first_name = nameArr[0];
    formData.last_name = nameArr[nameArr.length - 1];
  }
  return formData;
};
$scope.change = function () {
  var newName = $scope.splitName($scope.contact.NAME);
  $scope.contact.FNAME = newName.first_name;
  $scope.contact.LNAME = newName.last_name;
};
//$scope.data = {
//  full_name: 'Joe Middle Name Smith',
//  first_name: '',
//  last_name: '',
//}
//var example = $scope.splitName($scope.data.full_name);
 }
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps are fairly easy.

Move the same function to factory and return a reference to it.

Inject factory in components that need to access it.

Then instead of using the scope referenced function use `ServiceName.ServiceMethod()`

```
appControllers.controller('ContactCtrl', ['$scope','Utilities', function ($scope, Utilities) {
    $scope.page.setDirection('none');

    $scope.change = function () {
        // use new factory method
        var newName = Utilities.splitName($scope.contact.NAME);
        $scope.contact.FNAME = newName.first_name;
        $scope.contact.LNAME = newName.last_name;
    };
}
]);

angular.module('myApp').factory('Utilities', function(){
    function splitName (fullName) {
        var formData = {},
                nameArr = fullName.split(' ');
        if (nameArr.length == 1) {
            formData.first_name = nameArr[0];
            formData.last_name = '';
        } else if (nameArr.length > 2) {
            formData.last_name = nameArr.pop();
            formData.first_name = nameArr.join(' ');
        } else {
            formData.first_name = nameArr[0];
            formData.last_name = nameArr[nameArr.length - 1];
        }
        return formData;
    }
    // return object with any factory properties needed
    return {
        splitName : splitName
        // add more properties as needed to expand functionality of factory
    }

})
```

Comment: Brilliant. I came pretty close to that but after a few hours with no success I thought best to reach out, thank you!